# Query from Oracle 10g to 11g

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am developing an automatization with `Oracle 11g`. I have the following query that works fine on `oracle 10g` but not 11.

```
update(
    select rirr.NUM_SERIE_ULT, 
           tri.T_USED_IMEI, 
           rirr.celular, 
           tri.MSISDN, 
           rirr.TRAFICO,
           case when rirr.celular =  tri.MSISDN then 'MISMO ABONADO' 
                when rirr.celular <> tri.MSISDN then 'OTRO ABONADO' 
                else 'SIN TRAFICO'
           end  as TRAFICO_ACTUALIZAR 
    from RENOVACIONES_INT_RENO_REPO rirr
         left join TRAFICO_RENOVACION_INTERNA tri
         on rirr.NUM_SERIE_ULT = tri.T_USED_IMEI
    )
set TRAFICO = TRAFICO_ACTUALIZAR;
```

Comment: Welcome  to SO.  Please detail what is not "working"

Comment: To backup OldProgrammer we know the query isn't working but please provide more details. Are you receiving an error, if you are what is it. Does it run but not update as you would expect it to (and there are no errors)?? Please provide more.

Comment: When i run this query appears the next error: "ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table." and this error start to appear when i upgrade oracle 10g to 11g

Comment: So, have you got all the constraints in 11g that you had in 10g?

Answer (score 1):

The error:

You are updating the column `TRAFICO` from table `rirr` (not the actual table name, but the alias you use for it in the query). This table is joined to table `tri` on the join condition `rirr.NUM_SERIE_ULT = tri.T_USED_IMEI`.

For each row in `rirr`, Oracle must find a unique row in `tri` where the join condition is satisfied. This means: column `NUM_SERIE_ULT` in table `rirr` may have duplicates; but column `T_USED_IMEI` in table `tri` must be UNIQUE (must not have duplicates). IN ADDITION, in Oracle's implementation of UPDATE statements using joins, it is required (and was in Oracle 10, I believe) that table `tri` have a UNIQUE index or UNIQUE constraint on column `T_USED_IMEI`. If the UPDATE statement worked in Oracle 10, it is very likely you had such an index or constraint.

Does such an index or constraint still exist in Oracle 11? If all you did was an upgrade, it should not have deleted/removed indexes or constraints; but that IS what the error message means...

Unrelated observation:

What is the point of selecting **other** columns in the SELECT subquery of the UPDATE? Namely: `rirr.NUM_SERIE_ULT, tri.T_USED_IMEI, rirr.celular, tri.MSISDN`. The first two appear in the join condition; the other two appear in the definition of `TRAFICO_ACTUALIZAR`. But that doesn't mean you need *any* of those four columns to also appear separately in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: Hi Mathguy, the previous statement worked well on Oracle 10 but i dont know when the dba upgraded to 11 a lot of querys stop work, i understand the problem, i dont care the other columns. I just want to update one table with the values of the other table (case statement). But in this momnet i dont know how to modify this query.